# How to implement a multiple user login for tests that are extracting login details from a file that holds the user ids

Tags: java, testng, synchronized, multiple-login, parallel-execution

I have a web application which I am testing with Selenium and Maven running parallel tests. At the moment, I am defining the login ids for every test. What I need is a solution where I will have a pool of users available to the tests. While the execution runs the tests will pick user ids to login from this pool. Once a parallel test is done the user Id should be released and become available to the next tests. The pool should be monitored and tests should be executed only when one or more users are available so I will avoid failures due to users unavailability.

I am new to this, so I am looking for some ideas / advises how I can implement the above. I am using Java.

Comment: You'll need to put them in some sort of datastore and handle this yourself. You're basically describing the behavior of a generic resource pool, so looking at how database pools work might be useful.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of how many tests can run in parallel at the same time? are we talking 2, 10 or 1000? I am not sure it is a good idea to have your tests depend on a small pool as that will tie them together and potentially create bottlenecks. Imagine tests crashing and not releasing users, you might even get all users locked, and no more tests could run

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining user's availability as boolean. Consider those four classes:

Class to define testUser as a Object:

```
package theo;

public class testUser {

    public String id;
    public String pwd;
    public boolean availability;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public boolean getAvailability() {
        return availability;
    }

    public void setAvailability(boolean availability) {
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    public testUser(String id, String pwd, boolean availability) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.availability = availability;
    }
}
```

Class with testUsers:

```
package theo;

public class testUsers {

    testUser Jessica = new testUser("Jessica", "Jessica's password", true);
    testUser Julie = new testUser("Julie", "Julie's password", false);
    testUser Jane = new testUser("Jane", "Jane's password", true);

    public testUser[] allTestUsers = {
            Jessica,
            Julie,
            Jane
    };
}
```

Class with test method:

```
package theo;

public class testMethod extends testUsers {

    public void testWhatever(testUser user) {

        System.out.println("Starting test with " + user.getId() + "'s credentials.");       
        user.setAvailability(false);        
        System.out.println(user.getId() + "'s availability is: " + user.getAvailability());     
        String id = user.getId();
        String pwd = user.getPwd();     
        // load login page, perform login and desired tests
        // ...      
        // possibly logout the user
        // ...      
        System.out.println("Login test finished, going to release user.");

        // and releasing the user
        user.setAvailability(true);

        System.out.println(user.getId() + "'s availability is: " + user.getAvailability());

    }
}
```

Class to perform tests due to user's availability:

```
package theo;

import org.junit.Test;

public class testDemo extends testMethod {

    @Test
    public void performTestDueToUserAvailability() {
        for (testUser testUser: allTestUsers) {
            if (testUser.getAvailability()) {
                testWhatever(testUser);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("User locked, skipping test.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting test with Jessica's credentials.
Jessica's availability is: false
Login test finished, going to release user.
Jessica's availability is: true
User locked, skipping test.
Starting test with Jane's credentials.
Jane's availability is: false
Login test finished, going to release user.
Jane's availability is: true
```

Comment: I wouldn't skip a test, when you run a  test suite, you want all your tests to run

Comment: In general yes, I agree. But "...tests should be executed only when one or more users are available..." The condition in performTestDueToUserAvailability() can be customized.

Comment: right, I understand this sentence as waiting for available users to run tests. Waiting, not skipping.

Comment: I see. He can just add a function to wait until the user.getAvailability() returns true. For example wait max few minutes and throw TimeoutException.